# Javascript : missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I m trying to call a javascript function who add a marker on a Google Map.

Here my code :

```
   {% for entreprise in entreprises %}
        <script> addMarker({{ entreprise.latitude }},{{ entreprise.longitude }},{{ entreprise.nom}})</script>
   {% endfor %}
```

Here my function :

```
function addMarker(latitude,longitude,nom)
{
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
      map: map,
      label: nom,
      title: nom
    });

}
```

I get an error : `missing ) after argument list`
When I try to quote my variables like this :

```
<script> addMarker('{{ entreprise.latitude }}','{{ entreprise.longitude }}','{{ entreprise.nom}}')</script>
```

I get the error :

```
addMarker() is not defined.
```

How can I call my function in Twig ?

Thank you a lot for any help.

Comment: Which one is it? "missing ) after argument list" or "`addMarker()` is not defined"?

Comment: Can you not use template strings?

Comment: Hi, when I let without quote, I get "missing ) after argument list" error

Comment: Hi Adam, 

I don't understand your question. What do you mean by template strings please ?

Comment: How is addMaker defined? Is it an iife or closure? Is it globally available. Also template strings are part of ES6.

Comment: addMaker is in the same file, at the end. In <script> balise

Comment: They are part of twig. Anyways make sure your script with the addMarker is loaded before you dump the script tags to the source. (as in print order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

```
    {% for entreprise in entreprises %}
        <script> addMarker({{ entreprise.latitude }},{{ entreprise.longitude }},{{ entreprise.nom}})</script>
   {% endfor %}
```

You need to put the quote because `latitude`, `longtitude` and `nom` will have an output of php string and not as a variable of javascript so your guess to add `'` was right.

(But it's still better to right `<script>` outside a loop
better to have this

```
 <script>
   {% for entreprise in entreprises %}
        addMarker('{{ entreprise.latitude }}','{{ entreprise.longitude }}','{{ entreprise.nom}}')
   {% endfor %} 
</script>
```

2. Do you call your function before ? if you declare your function before it will of course say if is not define. So try to import the script before calling your function `addMarker`

Do you use jQuery () ? if so you can use

`$(document).ready(function(){});`

So you may get

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   {% for entreprise in entreprises %}
        addMarker('{{ entreprise.latitude }}','{{ entreprise.longitude }}','{{ entreprise.nom}}')
   {% endfor %} 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thank your for your help.

addMarker was not declared before the call. And I quoted only the string (entreprise.nom) and It worked ! Ty again !

Comment: Oh yeah, latitude and longitude seems to be float so yeah u don't need string :)